# Java: Setting "this" instance to an object of the same type

Tags: java

I have a POJO that has access to a method that returns an object of the same type (usually with some fields populated).  Is it possible to implement a method in the POJO that calls this getter method and sets the instance of the POJO to reference the object that is returned?  I would like to avoid setting a `copy()` function for every POJO that I create.

For example:

```
public class DAO {
    public static BaseEntity get(int id) {
        // returns some POJO
    }
}

public abstract class BaseEntity {
    public void get(int id) {
        BaseEntity entity = DAO.get(id);
        // sets "this" to the entity
    }
}

public class POJO extends BaseEntity {
    int foo;
    String bar; 
}
```

Comment: What has that got to do with a 'set this' ?
Since you can't instantiate BaseEntity, there will be no 'this' anyway.

Comment: POJO extends BaseEntity, so I'd like to be able to do something like `pojo.get(123)` to populate its fields.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do. I just don't get the logic of your 'how'. I would recommend an interface (not an abstract class) and a (concrete) implementation of that interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't assign to `this`.

You can have your `get` method return the new instance :

```
public BaseEntity get(int id) {
    return DAO.get(id);
}
```

And then assign that returned instance to the reference of the original instance:

```
BaseEntity pojo = new POJO ();
...
pojo = pojo.get(5);
```

Comment: I see, this makes sense.  Something that seems weird to me is that `pojo = pojo.get(5)` seems a bit redundant.  If I could just call `pojo.get(5)` and the object is updated, then that seems a lot more natural.  Is my thought process correct?

Comment: The first `new POJO();` is likely to be redundant.

Comment: @PeterLawrey The idea was to call an instance method that changes that instance (since that's what the OP seems to want), so an initial instance must be created in order to call pojo.get(5). Of course, you can directly call the static method.

Comment: @user2066880 For that purpose, `pojo.get(5)` would have to change the state of the existing instance. It can't change the `pojo` variable to refer to a different instance.

Answer (score 1):

> If I could just call pojo.get(5) and the object is updated,

What you really want is just

```
 BaseEntity pojo = DAO.get(id);
```

The only way to change a reference to an object is to return it.  Trying to wrapping it appears to just make your code more complicated in this case.